# While creating database: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, workbench

When I am creating a database, I'm getting a little bit of a difficulty with creating the "main" table for this database.

I thought there was a type difference between the foreign key and the primary key, but there wasn't.

So can anyone help me out? There must be something that I'm overlooking, but I can't find the problem.

```
[code]
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `boat`.`terms_and_conditions`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `boat`.`terms_and_conditions` (
  `Terms_And_Conditions_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Terms_And_Conditions_Doc` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terms_And_Conditions_Date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Terms_And_Conditions_Id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `boat`.`player`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `boat`.`player` (
  `Player_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Player_Firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Player_Lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Player_Password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Player_Budget` DOUBLE NULL,
  `Terms_Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Player_Id`),
  INDEX `fk_player_terms_and_conditions1_idx` (`Terms_Id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_player_player_result1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Player_Id`)
    REFERENCES `boat`.`player_result` (`Player_Id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_player_supervisor_player1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Player_Id`)
    REFERENCES `boat`.`supervisor_player` (`Player_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_player_terms_and_conditions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Terms_Id`)
    REFERENCES `boat`.`terms_and_conditions` (`Terms_And_Conditions_Id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Are you sure you get the error when trying to add foreign key to `terms_and_conditions` table? Are `player_result` and `supervisor_player` tables exist? What happens, if you try to create your `player` table without the `Terms_Id` foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the Primary Key in the Player Table. It was configured to act like a foreign key for the other tables.